# Is it possible to use OpenCV contour in python in a way that corners are not cut off?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am using the OpenCV contour function in python. For example on an image like this:

[image]

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_expanded_padded, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

[image]
It works well except that it cuts off the corners on the inside of the contour as seen above. Are there any options that would leave this corner in?

Travelling along the contours and filling them in manually will be too computationally expensive. The above is only an example. This will be performed many times on images 5400x5400 or more...

I can find the edges with the code below, and have filled corners as a result but then I need to extract these as contours again.

```
# FIND ALL HORIZONTAL AND VERTICAL EDGES AND COMBINE THEM
edges_expanded_x = np.absolute(cv2.Sobel(img_expanded_padded,cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3))
edges_expanded_y = np.absolute(cv2.Sobel(img_expanded_padded,cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3))
edges_expanded = np.logical_or(edges_expanded_x, edges_expanded_y)

# GET RID OF DOUBLE EDGE THAT RESULTS FROM SOBEL FILTER
edges_expanded = np.multiply(img_expanded_padded,edges_expanded)
```

Are there any OpenCV settings or functions I can use to accomplish this?

EDIT:
I should clarify, that my goal is to have a single pixel continous contour. I need the contours and not an array of the entire image including the contours.

EDIT: The above images are zoomed into my test image. The actual pixels are as shown by the red grids in the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `cv2.Sobel` you can simply draw contours with `cv2.drawContours` on a black background. The black background can be drawn with the help of np.zeros.

```
img = cv2.imread('contouring.png',0)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bgr = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype= 'uint8')
cv2.drawContours(bgr, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 1)
```

[image: thin egdes]

If you want the contour lines to be thick then you use `cv2.dilate` for that. Then to prevent the cutting of corners `cv2.bitwise_and` can be used along with `cv2.bitwise_not` as shown below

```
bgr = cv2.dilate(bgr, np.ones((31, 31), np.uint8), iterations=1)
bgr = cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, cv2.bitwise_not(img))
```

This gives contours which are 15 pixels thick.
[image: thick edges]

**EDIT**- The first image of thin contours is still cutting corners. To obtain single pixel contours which do not corners we can use a kernel size of 3*3.

```
img = cv2.imread('contouring.png',0)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bgr = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype= 'uint8')
cv2.drawContours(bgr, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 1)
bgr = cv2.dilate(bgr, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)
bgr = cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, cv2.bitwise_not(img))
```

This gives us
[image: RESULT]

I have checked it by using `cv2.bitwise_and` between bgr and img and I obtain a black image indicating that no white pixels are cutting corners.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem yet. I need a single pixel contours without the entire image. If I can get it along with the hierarchy than bonus.

Comment: Refer to the first part it has only a single pixel contour.

Comment: I know. I did that initially. Zoom into your image and you will see that the inner corners are missing. I clarified it with some additional immages in my question. Just doing contour as you are suggesting leaves these cut out corners.

Comment: @Janusz I checked it on a small matrix and indeed it is cutting corners. However to solve it you can can use `cv2.erode` with a kernel matrix of 3*3 and follow it with `bgr = cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, cv2.bitwise_not(img))`. I have edited my answer with these changes as well.

Comment: You didn't add the code so I'm not sure on what you want to run erode.

Just to clarify, the image being processed has many shapes and thus many contours. I used `cv2.findContour` because it produces a list of contours, each of which is an array of points (pixels) where each point (pixel) is adjacent to the subsequent point (point); the contour pixels are in order along a ring. Using the methods above, you always get back a background OR if you eliminate that, you just get an unordered set of white points (pixels).

Comment: I have added the full code. The result is in bgr. Please check the edit portion.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It give me some insight into OpenCV. Unfortunately, it still does not solve the problem. In essence, I need the data of the contours (rings) which are ordered points. Your method produces an image (with thin contours) but it is not possible to list the different contours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188359/discussion-between-vardan-agarwal-and-janusz).